# Term coined by author of a book related to curses

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, witches

I am looking for a "term" related to curses. The story it was used in was about a woman (a witch?) that was skilled at using words to make people believe they were cursed. She didn't need to put it in action, the words were enough and suficiently powerful that the one on whom they were cast believe it so much that the next missfortune that hit them made them atribute it to the curse.

So it isn't curses actually but how you think about a given situation, having previously been exposed to curse like words.

Does this sound familiar? Do you know to what book or character it refers to?

Comment: Not an uncommon theme, and very little to go on...

Comment: @dmckee: I know... That's why I can't find it through Googling. I don't know how to phrase the search words...

Comment: @John: You should post your newly gained information as an individual answer to your question, not edit it into the question text. That will allow you to accept it as answer.

Comment: @bitmask: I know but it's a waiting time for it and wanted to notify users so they don't waste anymore time on this. I'll add it as an answer when the time expires...

Comment: For reference 'headology' can be used to both bless and curse. Granny Weatherwax (mostly) uses it for good.

Answer (score 3):

## Headology

That's the term I was searching for. Finally found it.... and the lady is called [Granny Weatherwax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granny_Weatherwax).

I also found the original post: [What is headology in Discworld?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/what-is-headology-in-discworld)

Sorry for the vague question...

Answer (score 2):

In the Stephen King book [Thinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinner_%28novel%29) the main character is cursed by a gypsy using the single word "Thinner".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but nope! Wasn't this one... although it's the same idea. There is a name for this, that's what I'm looking for. How is that called?

Comment: @John It's been awhile, but I think in this one they call it a "hex".

Comment: "Hex" doesn't sound familiar. It's more close to a definition from psychology...